# Redshift doesn't work with Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I have a problem running a program called Redshift. When I open it it closes immediately. Here is the error when I try to run it from the terminal:

```bash
$ redshift 

(process:3525): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_instance_get_private: 
    assertion `instance != NULL && instance->g_class != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Looks like an error in that redshift program. Where is it from, how did you install it, can you give us more information on it? Is it that color-changing thing that helps you sleep?

Comment: Redshift the game? You should include more details Do you have the proprietary drivers for you card installed ?

Answer (score 3):

It might be redshift which can't figure out your location, as I believe it uses the Gnome-clock to do this.

Try go to http://www.getlatlon.com/ and type in your city. Then use the shown lat-/longitude in a terminal command as following:

```
redshift -l x:y

x = latitude (ex. 56.15)
y = longitude (ex. 10.12)

ex:
redshift -l 56.16:10.12
```